# How to add a vertical block throughout whole page in poster?

Tags: formatting, baposter

I made a poster of my work using 'baposter' template. However, Professor told me it's better to make the poster using Institute template as follows (which I dislike).

[image: Poster layout]

So my question is: how to customize the layout using existing  poster class? namely the two blocks: at top - "University and Institute Logo" and the vertical right side "Poster title and authors". The content will use the default settings (2-3 columns).

Comment: By institute template, do you mean an institute-specific `cls` or `sty`? If the picture is your reference, it would be really easy to build with a couple of minipages, right?

Comment: The picture is just the standard poster-layout. With baposter or other post class, it seems not easy to do this, since the block position has to be aligned to other blocks.